# Excel , find duplicates between 2 columns and displays return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Column A (list of suppliers from 2018) and then Column B (Supplier $ spent), column C (List of all our suppliers in our database).

My objectives are:

1. To find the duplicates , show them that they are a match so as they get displayed in the same row and return value of Column B for a match in Column D

OR

2. To search for duplicates and returns column B as a return value in Column D.

Comment: Current formula: =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)). But it does not sort and displays N/A for no matches. Any way to correct it ?

Comment: To add information to your question use the edit button on the bottom left of your post.

Comment: can you use vlookup to lookup column C in the table (colA, colB) and return column B for match?

Comment: Yup, it worked. I used ISERROR to root out any "N/A". Thank you

Comment: cool, Just added as answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vlookup` to lookup column C in the table (colA, colB) and return column B for the matches.

Something like -

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$6,2,FALSE),"")
```

Replace A$2:B$6 with your table range.